# Skin extra sensitive to heat after burn

Tags: physiology, human-anatomy, pain, perception

I just got my finger burnt (first degree burn $\Rightarrow$ I didn't even bother to bear the wound). It didn't hurt much, even when I pressed the wound.
However, when exposed to heat (hot water, but not so hot to hurt undamaged skin), the pain became *at least* nasty.

Is it an evolutionary adaptation to avoid hot objects not to get burnt again?

Comment: All traits that you observe have accumulated because of evolution. Is your question on enhanced sensitivity of burn area about its "how" or "why" ? Your reasoning on "why" is plausible and there is nothing much to say about that. Most "why" questions tend to have a philosophical aspect to it because we can at best, only make sensible guesses.

Comment: The burnt skin is *extra* sensitive because it is injured, just like a broken bone or a cut - it is the body's way of saying be gentle. The general evolution of pain, and sensitivity, acts to teach us to not repeat dangerous/harmful things, but this does not explain particularly why a burnt bit of flesh is *extra* sensitive.

Comment: Local inflammation (nerve receives inflammatory signaling molecules from its local environment) and direct injury can both increase the sensitivity of nociceptive (pain/noxious stimuli sensing) nerves. This sensitivity can drive animals to guard the injured area. This may be beneficial to survival. Persons unable to sense pain often accidentally self-injure, perhaps further sensitization helps protect the weak/injured area). So it's plausible, but as WYSIWYG said, we cannot prove why this behavior arose. We can only make reasonable conjectures.